# Finding a strictly increasing Collatz sequence of arbitrary length

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, recurrences, collatz-conjecture

Is there a formula to construct a Collatz (3x + 1) sequence of arbitrary length that is strictly increasing? Obviously one can do this with a strictly decreasing sequence by just taking $2^n$ but I haven't seen a way to do it with a strictly increasing sequence.

Comment: Presumably, you mean a $\frac{3x + 1}{2}$-sequence, since if $x$ is odd then $3x + 1$ is even. In that case: start with $x = 2^n - 1$, or more generally $x = m*2^n - 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a number equal to $-1$ modulo $2^n$. Then, after one step, the number is $\frac{3(-1)+1}{2}=-1$ modulo $\frac{2^n}{2}=2^{n-1}$, so inductively it will increase $n$ steps.